# TSQL Parse from XML nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, parsing

This XML comes from public treasury. SQL Server seems to think it is not XML?  My result says the XLT method can only be involved with column type XML. Is this result set from the treasury really XML?

How can I parse it into a SQL table?

[treasury daily market yield](https://data.treasury.gov/feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData?$filter=month(NEW_DATE)%20eq%207%20and%20year(NEW_DATE)%20eq%202020)

```
DECLARE @XML NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @XML = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData</title>
  <id>http://data.treasury.gov/feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData</id>
  <updated>2020-07-14T05:40:26Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData"/>
  <entry>
    <id>http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7633)</id>
    <title type="text"/>
    <updated>2020-07-14T05:40:26Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name/>
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7633)"/>
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7633</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2020-07-01T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.12</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_2MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.12</d:BC_2MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.14</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.17</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.16</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.17</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.19</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.31</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.52</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.69</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.2</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.43</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">1.43</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
</feed>'
   
SELECT  b.value('@d:Id', 'varchar(28)') as d_id
       ,b.value('@d:BC_30YEAR', 'double') as d_BC_30YEAR
  FROM @XML.nodes('feed/entry/content type/m:properties/') as a(b)
```

Comment: Change `DECLARE @XML NVARCHAR(MAX)` to `DECLARE @XML XML`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, define your `@XML` to be of type `XML`:

```
DECLARE @XML XML;
```

Then: you need to **define** the relevant XML namespaces involved!

Try this snippet of code:

```
-- define XML namespaces!
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom', 
                    'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata' AS m,
                    'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices' AS d)
SELECT  
    b.value('(d:Id)[1]', 'varchar(28)') as d_id,
    b.value('(d:BC_30YEAR)[1]', 'decimal(20,2)') as d_BC_30YEAR
FROM 
    @XML.nodes('feed/entry/content/m:properties') as a(b)
```

This returns the following value:

[image]

Fixes I made:

```
FROM @XML.nodes('feed/entry/content type/m:properties/') as a(b)  
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Wrong node name - the node is `<content>` (not "content type") - the `type` is just an attribute on the node, no relevant in this XPath here.

```
SELECT b.value('@d:Id', 'varchar(28)') as d_id  
                ^^^^^^
```

You really want to select the XML **element** (node) `d:Id` - not an attribute - the `@` in `@d:Id` denotes an attribute!

```
b.value('@d:BC_30YEAR', 'double') as d_BC_30YEAR  
                        ^^^^^^^^^
```

You need to use a proper T-SQL datatype - like `decimal(20,2)` - not "double"
here....

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thank you.

Comment: I do have this working fine in a stored procedure. Interestingly, it fails when schedule in a SQL Job. I've changed Agent to run as the same user I develop and and execute the SP with. Any ideas?